# Is it possible to iterate three arrays at the same time?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

We can iterate two arrays at the same time using Array's `zip` method like:

```
@budget.zip(@actual).each do |budget, actual|
  ...
end
```

Is it possible to iterate three arrays? Can we use the `transpose` method to do the same?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
>> [1,2,3].zip(["a","b","c"], [:a,:b,:c]) { |x, y, z| p [x, y, z] }
[1, "a", :a]
[2, "b", :b]
[3, "c", :c]
```

`transpose` also works but, unlike `zip`, it creates a new array right away:

```
>> [[1,2,3], ["a","b","c"], [:a,:b,:c]].transpose.each { |x, y, z| p [x, y, z] }
[1, "a", :a]
[2, "b", :b]
[3, "c", :c]
```

Notes:

- You don't need `each` with [zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip), it takes a block.
- Functional expressions are also possible. For example, using `map`: `sums = xs.zip(ys, zs).map { |x, y, z| x + y + z }`.
- For an arbitrary number of arrays you can do `xss[0].zip(*xss[1..-1])` or simply `xss.transpose`.

Comment: +1 Array manipulations, either via `zip`, `transpose` or the built-in set operations, are super-powerful tools in Ruby. You can crunch a lot of data fast with them.

Comment: Maybe worth noting `*` for any number of arrays?